# Raw response of a image/png resonpse

Tags: javascript, png, libpng

I am getting a response body with raw response, which is supposed to respresent a png image. My question is how to decode this and make it a renderable.

PS: when I am use postman to test this, I realized that Postman can render this raw string, and I am wondering how it does it.

> �PNG
>
> IHDR�X:�(�    pHYs���o�d
>   IDATx���\�w����v,J�L�2b�_٬�N��d��0|�*cmDN�6�y.�q�{�Iӌ�hsnNcl��g~/;"vʯ�m�('}�Q9��q�P(G:�������z=*���q��|=_�\�p�""""""�p�w""""""b
>   �""""""J�PDDDDD�A)������8(B�@("""""�EDDDDD���������R
>   qP
>   �""""""J�PDDDDD�A)������8(B�@("""""�EDDDDD���������R
>   [...]

Comment: `<img src="the/path/to/this/response">`

Comment: convert that byte stream to base64 and put the base64 string to `src` attribute of `img` tag

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of googling, I finally figured out the issue:
Essentially, the response from my REST call actually contains `blob` type of the png image. So to properly render it, we don't have to base64 the blob, instead it is natively supported by html5. The problem I was facing is that this `blob` is not supported by jQuery ajax call, hence higher level libraries like axios does NOT support it either.

For simplicity, to demo how this works, I would use jQuery:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Blob image/png demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/" id="invokeBlob">
  <input type="submit" value="Invoke It!">
</form>
<!-- the result of the blob will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="imgcontainer"></div>

<script>
  // Attach a submit handler to the form
  $( "#invokeBlob" ).submit(function( event ) {

    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = "https://YOUR-DOMAIN/charts";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer XXX-YOUR-JWT-TOKEN")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "image/png");
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        var blob = this.response;
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.onload = function(e) {
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
        };
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $("#imgcontainer").html(img);
      }
    }
    xhr.send();
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```