# How do I display raw png response from API on browser?

Tags: php, jquery, curl, png

I have tried to display a raw png image from api on my browser using Curl, and below is what I have tried; but I am receiving black image with a little square at the middle. But When I use the same url on post man the imgage is displayed properly. Please kindly assist, look through my codes and see what I am doing wrong. Also I tried to check this out [Raw response of a image/png resonpse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210068/raw-response-of-a-image-png-resonpse) but it is not giving the same thing, I tried searching for others and nothing much is given.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://url",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxx"
    ),
));

$response= curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);


$size = filesize($response);
header("Content-length: $size"); 
header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename ="image.png"');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image.png"');
$png= file_put_contents("image.png", $response);


echo $response; gives this     ����JFIF���� ICC_PROFILE mntrRGB XYZ acspAPPL���- desc�|cprtx(wtpt�bkpt�rXYZ�gXYZ�bXYZ�rTRCgTRCbTRCdesc"Artifex
```

On var_dump($response); I receive a string of this type

```
string(64086) "�PNG  IHDR� ����,bKGD���̿ pHYs��U[��tIME�2�b��IDATx���-��L�������J��JNYղ���:V�uDVY���`떗^�Һ�`�����Bv�;���#�kO2��p�0/��O���.ψ�`,...
```

I have the raw data on this link:https://pastebin.com/Q5rNu6dX

string(198663) "�PNG  IHDRm ��1Џ &iCCPiccH���gP�Y���<�@B�PC�*%��Z(ҫ�@�PEl��+��4E�E\�"kE��t�,ʺqQAYp���?���{�o�s��s��p ��e��{bR���Ɏ��(������t�ջ��{������i�常�r�)�t��e��JOY��L���gWX�\�2�X��y�Kο,�����]~

Comment: _“On var_dump($response); I receive a string of this type”_ - and using `filesize` on _that_ at the very start of your script made sense to you how exactly then? Should probably use `strlen` there instead, no?

Comment: _"but I am receiving black image with a little square at the middle"_ - So what are you expecting? That doesn't sound like a broken image. What do you see if you open the image you saved?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it shows "fatal error displaying png, not a png file"

Comment: Then it sounds like there's an issue with how you populate the `$response` variable. Please show us _all_ relevant code.

Comment: @CBroe I tried "strlen" and the same error.

Comment: So what do you see when you inspect the response using your browser dev tools?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson $response is the data received from API call and that same end point used on Postmaster displays without issues. How to display the response from my browser or store it to my local machine is the issue. But I have added the curl to my code above.

Comment: @CBroe it says "this request has no response data available"

Comment: Change `header("Content-length: $size");` to `header("Content-length: ". strlen($response));` and then comment out `header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image.png"');`... leave `echo $response;`.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Still the same issue. I var_dump($response); and it is blank.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I responded to the code you supplied. My question still stands..I said When I do it the way you suggested that var_dump($response); is empty.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I understand you are trying to assist. I am only reporting what I experienced. When I comment out all the codes below "curl_close($curl);" and var_dump($response) it shows back the binary data.